# Determining the max area of a trapezoid with no known sides

Tags: calculus, optimization

A trapezoid is drawn inside a semi circle cross section with the upper base length, being the length of the circle diameter, $d$, and a lower base, $x$, touching the lower sides of the semi circle.

What is the maximum length of the lower base, $x$, of the trapezoid if its area is to be a maximum?
What is the maximum are of the trapezoidal cross section in terms of $d$?

So far I have determined from $A=(\frac{x+d}2)h$, that $h$ is equal to $\sqrt{(\frac{d}2)^2 - (\frac{x}2)^2}$

And therefore $A$ in terms of $x$ & $d$.

$$A=(\frac{x+d}2)(\sqrt{(\frac{d}2)^2 - (\frac{x}2)^2}$$

$$A=(\frac{x+d}2)(\sqrt{\frac{d^2}4 - \frac{x^2}4})$$

$$A=(\frac{x+d}2)(\frac{\sqrt{d^2 - x^2}}2)$$

$$A= \frac14 (x+d) (\sqrt{d^2 - x^2})$$

this is where I got stuck... help?

Comment: So far you've expressed A in terms of x and d. As d is a constant, A is only    subject to x. You should now evaluate $\frac{dA}{dx}$ to find out the turning points, thus the corresponding x. You may need to apply chain rule.

Answer (score 2):

Answer:

I really do not know what the problem is when you got the steps absolutely right.

If differentiation is the problem:

$$\frac{dA}{dx} = \sqrt{d^2-x^2} + (x+d) \frac{-2x}{2\sqrt{d^2-x^2}}$$

$$\frac{dA}{dx} = 0$$

Assuming two functions $U = x+d$ and $V = \sqrt{d^2-x^2}$

$$\frac{dA}{dx} = V\frac{dU}{dx}+U\frac{dV}{dx}$$
$\frac{dU}{dx} = 1$  and $\frac{dV}{dx} = \frac{-2x}{2\sqrt{d^2-x^2}}$

$$\frac{dA}{dx} =  \sqrt{d^2-x^2}+(x+d)\frac{-2x}{2\sqrt{d^2-x^2}} = d^2-x^2 -x(x+d) $$ $$= d^2 - 2x^2-xd = 2x^2 +xd-d^2=0$$  This a quadratic with x as the variable and two roots of x in terms of d is what follows.

the two roots of a quadratic$ax^2+bx+c = 0$ is as follows:

$$ x= \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$.

In our case $a = 2$, $b = d$ and $c = -d^2$

\begin{align}
 x &= \frac{-d\pm\sqrt{d^2 + 8d^2}}{4}\\
 &= \frac{-d\pm\sqrt{9d^2}}{4}\\  &= \frac{-d\pm3d}{4}\\
  &= \frac{d}{2} \text{ or } \frac{-2d}{2}\text{ (rej.)}\\
\end{align}.

Now substitute the value of d in the area and find A in terms of d.

Goodluck

Thanks
Satish

Comment: The denominator of x should be 4, not 6.

Comment: @Narasimham,  careless mistake, Fixed it.  Thanks

Comment: @HelmutGunnie, I have shown the steps.

Comment: @HelmutGunnie, see the edited solution.  I hope you understand now.  Thanks

Comment: @HelmutGunnie, in the step where you find the dA/dx, since you are setting it to 0, you multiply the $\sqrt{d^2-r^2} $in the second term to the first term and hence it is $d^2-r^2$ and do not care about the denominator anymore. The numerator gets $d^2-r^2$ and $-x(x+d)$ and addition of them you set  it to 0 and again multiply by -1 so that you  get a quadratic in x.  I did not realize that my solution is not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to continue differentiating the product by Chain Rule.

If $v \cdot v $ = const, then $ \dfrac{u}{v} = -\dfrac {u^{'}}{v^{'} } $

$ \dfrac{x+d}{\sqrt {d^2-x^2 }}$ =  $ -\dfrac{-\sqrt {d^2-x^2 }}{x} $

Cross multiply and simplify,

$ (x-d/2) (x +d ) = 0, $ from which the first root is taken and the second one rejected.

Incidentally note that solution $ x = ( d/2= r ) $ is giving you bottom half of a regular hexagon, a solution adopted by civil engg. in canal digging for maximum water flow section area.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to assume the quadrilateral is a trapezoid. Connect the two free vertices to the center with radii, thus dividing the area into three isosceles triangles. Let the three vertex angles at the circle center be ${\theta}_1,{\theta}_2$ and ${\theta}_3$. Let the radius of the circle be one. Then the area of the quadrilateral is $\frac12(\sin{\theta}_1+\sin{\theta}_2+\sin{\theta}_3)$, together with constraint that the sum of the three angles is 180 degrees. The sine function is concave downward over the range from zero to 180 degrees, so we can apply Jensen's inequality. This gives the maximum area when the three angles are equal.